# Switch between Custom textviews according to custom themes in android application

Tags: android-layout, textview, android, android-theme

In my application I am implementing `5 different Custom App Themes`.

I am using 5 different fonts for these themes for which I have created `CustomTextview` which extends a `Textview`. Following is the format in which it is created.

```
public class CustomFontTextView extends TextView {
private static final String CUSTOM_FONT = "Custom-Regular.ttf";
private static final String TAG = CustomFontTextView.class.getName();

public CustomFontTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
        setCustomFont(context, CUSTOM_FONT);
    }
}

public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
        setCustomFont(context, CUSTOM_FONT);
    }
}

public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
        setCustomFont(context, CUSTOM_FONT);
    }    
}

public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String fontFile) {
    try {
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), fontFile));       
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I was using the custom textview in the XML layouts.

```
    <com.myapp.android.fonts.CustomFontTextView
    android:id="@+id/Text_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/my_text_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

But for implementing the different themes I have to find some methods which would change all my textviews according to the themes selected.

Is there any way by which I can set the fonts within my theme,

```
      <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
               ..............   ......................
             ...........     ...................
         <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
         <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyCustomButton</item>
      </style>
```

I want to implement this without disturbing the code as there are a lot of UI components involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom attribute for the font and include it in the style. In your CustomView class, access this attribute and set the font accordingly.

Check [Creating a View Class](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Will I be able to implement this by creating **TextView** instead of customTextview in XML layout? I want to use single XML layout for displaying 5 different fonts at different times(_when different themes are selected_). The `com.myapp.android.fonts.CustomFontTextView` which i am using in my layout is not allowing me to do that..!